# specifying DEVELOPER_DIR to choose xcode version have no impact in jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

[image]i'm trying to switch between different xcode versions with jenkins and i come to this solution where we inject DEVELOPER_DIR as environment variables

DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode8.1.app/Contents/Developer.

but even if xcodebuild -version show the correct as xcode8.1 my project fail because it uses the other version of xcode7 .

Thanks for your help

Comment: try echoing your path in a shell command in groovy to see if  you're already including a path to xcode

Comment: can you please tell me how , i didn't get it

Comment: in a groovy script: sh "echo \$PATH"

Comment: i tried println System.getenv("DEVELOPER_DIR") and the result was null , and when i use echo $DEVELOPER_DIR as shell script , it gives me the right path to xcode8. 
sh "echo \$PATH" won't works

Comment: try sh "which xcodebuild" just as a sanity check

Comment: /usr/bin/xcodebuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of info in the documentation for the [Xcode plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin), some of which could help you debug your PATH issue, but you'll probably find it easier to just use this plugin to configure Xcode.

Comment: thanks for your help , it works now after using the xcode plugin

Comment: Great, glad to help, for next steps: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers